# A working way to sort a TListView column that contains a DateTime value

Tags: delphi, sorting, listview

I have a TListView wit 3 columns. Column 1 is Text, Column 2 is Text and Column 3 is DateTime
For now I have the following code on my form

```
function CompareTextAsDateTime(const s1, s2: string): Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareDateTime(StrToDateTime(s2), StrToDateTime(s1));
end;

procedure TfrmHsMailCollect.lstMailsColumnClick(Sender: TObject; Column: TListColumn);
begin
  TListView(Sender).SortType := stBoth;
end;

procedure TfrmHsMailCollect.lstMailsCompare(Sender: TObject; Item1, Item2: TListItem; Data: Integer; var Compare: Integer);
begin
  Compare := CompareTextAsDateTime(Item1.subitems[colDate - 1], Item2.subitems[colDate - 1]);
  Compare := -Compare;
end;
```

The -Compare is because the column needs to be sorted descending so newest item is the first one.
My problem is that the column isn't sorted.
I have been looking at several solutions both here on this website and others, but they all looks the same and none is working.

So my question is: what is the correct way to sort a TListView column that contains a DateTime value.

Answer (score 2):

The `SortType` property is not what you need here. That is used for automatic sorting. You don't want that, you want to sort in response to user action.

You instead need to call the `CustomSort` method:

```
procedure TfrmHsMailCollect.lstMailsColumnClick(Sender: TObject; Column: TListColumn);
begin
  TListView(Sender).CustomSort(nil, 0);
end;
```

The first argument to `CustomSort` is the compare function. If `nil` is passed then the comparison is routed to the `OnCompare` event, which I trust to be `lstMailsCompare` in your code.

The second argument of `CustomSort` is passed to the compare method as its `Data` argument. You are not using that mechanism and so can pass anything you like. You could use it to specify whether or not the ordering should be ascending or descending, for instance.